# Send non-printing character binary sms in android

Tags: java, android, encoding, sms

I am developing a crypted sms app, I am crypting the sms to 3DES and I am trying to send the byte array result to the other phone using SmsManager.sendDataMessage but I am not able to read the right byte array in the receiver phone, for example:

My app sends the array:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-100,-101,-105,-110]
```

and in the other phone, I receive only (if lucky)

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

I have tried sending as text with many encodings but it is not working.

I tried it on simulators and in devices and the behaviour is the same.

I tried sending bytes from printable characters (letters, numbers) and it works perfectly, so I 
think the problem are the non-printing bytes, but I need to send the bytes trough sms.... a friend made something like that but using blackberry and it worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code for sending:

```
SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
byte[] arrBytes = new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-100,-101,-105,-110};

manager.sendDataMessage(number, null, (short)0, arrBytes, null, null);
```

This is the code for receiving:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] smsMensajes = null;
    if(bundle != null){
        try{
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            smsMensajes = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            byte[] msjByte = new byte[100];

            for(int i=0; i < smsMensajes.length; i++){
                smsMensajes[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                msjByte = smsMensajes[i].getUserData();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Recibiendo SMS", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fundamentally trying to send arbitrary bytes through a text-based interface, the safest way to do so is to use base-64. There's a [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class in Android which makes this very easy.

Admittedly this means the size is inflated a bit, so in 140 characters you'll only transmit 105 bytes, but at least it's safe and should work with *any* device and API.

Comment: I am trying yo send bytes in bytes way, not in text way, but I don't know why, the bytes I send, are not received. And, base64 is an option but we are are trying to avoid it by the fact that it reduces the data length we can transmit over the SMS. I am trying bytes because my friend did it with blackberry and I think android can do what bb can do. And because bb have to undestand what android send s and android have to understand what bb sends, in other words, the sms will be sent from a device to another device.

Comment: @oware: The problem is that the SMS is inherently a text medium, as far as APIs go. You can't send "bytes in bytes way" because you only get to talk to the API in terms of text. While you could *try* to find appropriate characters to map every binary value, I think you're very, very likely to run into problems with different platforms decoding the SMS in subtly different ways. Go ahead and experiment if you want, but my *strong* believe is that base64 is the most robust way to go here, and that it'll save you a lot of heartache.

Comment: Well, we finally used base64 to encode the bytes and send it over the sms... I will mark your answer as correct because you suggested that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to flush streams before you close them. Looks like you're not working with streams though. Then I would guess some length param is wrong.

If you're after encryption then why not send an encrypted string? No need to try bytes. Check this snippet: http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

Out of curiosity: how are you managing the secret key for encryption/decryption on both ends?

Comment: There are no streams present in the question - just a byte array.

Comment: Encryption works perfectly locally, I save it in base64, and the key, every end have a key that shares with the other end